# How to read both double and int from a file in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I have this input file that I am trying to read with scanner.The file looks like this.

```
20 0.4
3  5.6
```

As you see it has an int and then a double and this goes on until the end of the file.I tried reading both of them as doubles:

```
while(scanner.hasNextDouble()){
    x = (int) scanner.nextDouble();
    y = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

And I also tried this:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    x = scanner.nextInt();
    y = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

But none of them seems to work.What may be a solution to this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what "none of them seems to work" means? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: a) Read the values as `String`s, e.g. line, wise b) split each line at `" "` c) parse the first compoonent to an `int` and the second component to a `double` (via [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and  [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @dunni  this error occurs :Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: @helen Then your input is not as stated.

Comment: @Turing85 I did what you suggested and it worked!Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop works fine.

**PROOF**

```
String input = "20 0.4\n" +
               "3 5.6\n";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    double y = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("x=%d, y=%f%n", x, y);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
x=20, y=0.400000
x=3, y=5.600000
```

This is what is called a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).